# MYSQL is shutting down... What is wrong?

Tags: mysql

1 time per week my mysql server is shutting down. Look at this logs:

```
2016-03-18 13:46:25 13166 [Warning] Buffered warning: Changed limits: max_open_files: 1024 (requested 5000)
2016-03-18 13:46:25 13166 [Warning] Buffered warning: Changed limits: table_open_cache: 431 (requested 2000)
2016-03-18 13:46:25 13166 [Warning] Using unique option prefix myisam-recover instead of myisam-recover-options is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.
2016-03-18 13:46:25 13166 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2016-03-18 13:46:25 13166 [ERROR] Function 'innodb' already exists
2016-03-18 13:46:25 13166 [Warning] Couldn't load plugin named 'innodb' with soname 'ha_innodb.so'.
2016-03-18 13:46:25 13166 [ERROR] Function 'federated' already exists
2016-03-18 13:46:25 13166 [Warning] Couldn't load plugin named 'federated' with soname 'ha_federated.so'.
2016-03-18 13:46:25 13166 [ERROR] Function 'blackhole' already exists
2016-03-18 13:46:25 13166 [Warning] Couldn't load plugin named 'blackhole' with soname 'ha_blackhole.so'.
2016-03-18 13:46:25 13166 [ERROR] Function 'archive' already exists
2016-03-18 13:46:25 13166 [Warning] Couldn't load plugin named 'archive' with soname 'ha_archive.so'.
2016-03-18 13:46:25 13166 [Note] InnoDB: Using atomics to ref count buffer pool pages
2016-03-18 13:46:25 13166 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2016-03-18 13:46:25 13166 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2016-03-18 13:46:25 13166 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
2016-03-18 13:46:25 13166 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
2016-03-18 13:46:25 13166 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2016-03-18 13:46:25 13166 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
2016-03-18 13:46:25 13166 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M InnoDB: mmap(137363456 bytes) failed; errno 12
2016-03-18 13:46:25 13166 [ERROR] InnoDB: Cannot allocate memory for the buffer pool
2016-03-18 13:46:25 13166 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
2016-03-18 13:46:25 13166 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
2016-03-18 13:46:25 13166 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
2016-03-18 13:46:25 13166 [ERROR] Aborting
2016-03-18 13:46:25 13166 [Note] Binlog end
2016-03-18 13:46:25 13166 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'partition'
2016-03-18 13:46:25 13166 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA'
2016-03-18 13:46:25 13166 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_DATAFILES'
2016-03-18 13:46:25 13166 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESPACES'
2016-03-18 13:46:25 13166 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete

160318 13:46:25 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended
```

What do you think? Maybe not enought memory? VPS Ubuntu 15.10 512MB.

Comment: Now I can't even restart my MySQL. It is very bad.

Comment: Really better suited to the [DBA site](http://dba.stackexchange.com).

Comment: It's right there in the logs: `[Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M InnoDB: mmap(137363456 bytes) failed; errno 12`. `[ERROR] InnoDB: Cannot allocate memory for the buffer pool`. You're probably out of memory. This can happen if you have too little memory and some other process (or processes) is sucking down all your memory. 512MB physical and 2G virtual can go quick.